# Where does this question belong?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, off-topic

> [Can My Personal GMail Query A Remote LDAP Server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/132969/)

Is there no right location for this question?

It seems to be off-topic no matter where I put it.

It's ironic because it was OT in SO, and I moved it to SU, and it was OT there, so I moved it to SF, and now it's OT there, but the discussion was coming right back to a programming discussion on how to do it.

I love this site for it's easy-question-easy-answer, but asking the question is starting to become more difficult than solving the problem.

I can't speak for everyone, obviously, but as a new user, this is the kind of frustrating thing that would drive me away from the site, and that seems like exactly the kind of reaction you guys are looking to avoid.

Comment: Sometimes it sucks, i.g.if there are tags like career-development and if someone dares toask a career-development related question he will be stone to death

Comment: FYI: I reopened the question on Serverfault. I think it should get a chance somewhere in the trilogy.

Comment: If it would have been on-topic on another site, then people who voted to close would have migrated the question automatically. (Please note that re-posting the same question on other sites just makes it hard to maintain clean sites.)

Comment: @Arjan: It only takes 3 random people to prevent (or force) migration while closing.  Sometimes it's appropriate to post elsewhere, if you believe it's on-topic there.

Comment: @Gnome, alright, *sometimes* maybe, but even then only *after* closing (and after giving giving the FAQs some thought -- apparently this very question has made to all 4 sites, including Meta...)

Comment: @arjan And it appears this user has given it some thought, and it does fit somewhere between *and* outside the trilogy, hence the confusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there no right location for this question?

There is no right location for that particular question.

You might try serverfault for "How do I get all the contacts off an LDAP server (so I can import them into my user's email programs that don't connect to LDAP)?"

You might try stackoverflow for "How do I write an LDAP client to pull all the contacts off an LDAP server?"

But you aren't going to be able to get help with gmail on any site in the trilogy.

Comment: i'd assume one could ask on SO about writing a Greasemonkey script to handle the gmail-to-LDAP glue, but that might be a stretch.

Comment: @quack .... and soon you're out in the field, shaving a yak...

Comment: .. and why do you want to shave it?  you just need the hooves to make the glue!

Answer (score 3):

This would be a Super User question if you had asked about configuring Thunderbird,  <strike>or Eudora,</strike> or Mutt, or Pine, or some other locally-installed email client to perform the same task.

But websites and web applications are offtopic on Super User.  Because your question asks how to configure the Gmail web client for this task, it falls afoul of the webapp policy, and is considered offtopic there.

This leaves your question (and others like it) orphaned and alone in the cold with no home among the Trilogy.

But have a waffle and look around; you may have other questions that are ontopic for these sites.  And the Trilogy is still growing, so it's entirely possible a web-app-centric site will spring up in, oh, 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: Eudora is still around?

Comment: @balpha: well, i couldn't think of another locally-installed email client offhand.  outlook doesn't count (ask the magic eight-ball if you don't know why).

Comment: @balpha: I just installed Eudora recently to test something - it's still around.

Answer (score 2):

I find it more of SU question than SF, but if the SU community chose to close it...  I agree with John Gardnier's comment on your SF post.  You should really contact Google to find out if it's possible, or if they have a service that will allow you to do that.

Answer (score 1):

you're asking a very specific question about a particular vendor; the logical thing to do is *ask google*